# ID variable not shown after creating object and passing it to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, json.net

I've done a POST method that takes object `Recipe` and inserts its values in the database using Dapper. I've written the SQL query so that when a new entry is inserted, the ID value will be autogenerated as: the maximum existing value in the database + 1. See code below:

```
 using (var con = _connFactory())
            {
                con.Open();
                con.Execute(@"INSERT INTO dbo.Recipe (Id, Name, RecipeLink, Category1Id ,Category2Id, Category3Id, Category4Id, RecipeById,
                            TotalTime, TotalTimeUnitId, ActiveTime, ActivetimeUnitId, Instructions, SourceKey, RecipeBy, InsertedAtUtc, IsVerified, NumPersons, ServingsUnitId, ServingsUnitOrig) 
                            VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM dbo.Recipe), @name, @recipeLink, @category1Id, @category2Id, @category3Id, @category4Id, @recipeById,
                            @totalTime, @totalTimeUnitId, @activeTime, @activeTimeUnitId, @instructions, @sourceKey, @recipeBy, getutcdate(), @isVerified, @numPersons, @servingsUnitId, @servingsUnitOrig)",
                            new
                            {
                                ...
                                ...
                            });
            }
```

When I send the request to the API using Postman, the returned result will be the newly created object that has been passed to the database. However, though, because of the way that my ID is created, the returned JSON looks like this:

```
{
"id": 0,
"name": "Test Recipe2",
"recipeLink": "testlink",
"category1Id": 7757,
...
"servingsUnitId": 3,
"servingsUnitOrig": null
}
```

As you can see, the ID is 0. But if I try to get the object after this, the ID will be set to the proper one, the one generated from `(SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM dbo.Recipe)`.

Is there any way in which I can make the API return the correct ID after the execution of the `INSERT INTO`? Or how should I change the logic behind the auto generation in order to achieve this?

It will come quite in handy if I was able to get the ID's value directly as now I've made a method that returns the ID of the latest Recipe created. But that might be a problem in case that there are 2 recipes created in a short period of time.

Comment: Is `Id` column an auto-increment? Can't you use `OUTPUT` clause or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`?

Comment: @Sami I didn't know about the `OUTPUT` clause until now. I will look into it and see how it helps. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `return` the `Id` and use `ExecuteScalar` to get it. In the execute Statement `declare` & generate next Id and the the end `select the NewId value`

```
 using (var con = _connFactory())
        {
            con.Open();
            var addedId = con.ExecuteScalar(@"DECLARE @NewId INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) + 1 FROM dbo.Recipe);INSERT INTO dbo.Recipe (Id, Name, RecipeLink, Category1Id ,Category2Id, Category3Id, Category4Id, RecipeById,
                        TotalTime, TotalTimeUnitId, ActiveTime, ActivetimeUnitId, Instructions, SourceKey, RecipeBy, InsertedAtUtc, IsVerified, NumPersons, ServingsUnitId, ServingsUnitOrig) 
                        VALUES (@NewId, @name, @recipeLink, @category1Id, @category2Id, @category3Id, @category4Id, @recipeById,
                        @totalTime, @totalTimeUnitId, @activeTime, @activeTimeUnitId, @instructions, @sourceKey, @recipeBy, getutcdate(), @isVerified, @numPersons, @servingsUnitId, @servingsUnitOrig); SELECT @NewId",
                        new
                        {
                            ...
                            ...
                        });
             //use addedId here...
        }
```

I would strongly suggest that you change the Id behavior to use either SQL-Server `Sequence` or `IDENTITY`. Using `select max()` can generate duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Select the id and call `Query` to retrieve it:

```
const string Sql = @"
INSERT INTO dbo.Recipe (...) VALUES (....);
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)";

int id = con.Query<int>(Sql, new { ...}).Single();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Auto Increment  and change table
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Recipe DROP COLUMN Id
ALTER TABLE dbo.Recipe ADD Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

After that, you don't need a pass id field in your query.

```
  con.Execute(@"INSERT INTO dbo.Recipe (Name, RecipeLink, Category1Id ,Category2Id, Category3Id, Category4Id, RecipeById,
                            TotalTime, TotalTimeUnitId, ActiveTime, ActivetimeUnitId, Instructions, SourceKey, RecipeBy, InsertedAtUtc, IsVerified, NumPersons, ServingsUnitId, ServingsUnitOrig) 
                            VALUES (@name, @recipeLink, @category1Id, @category2Id, @category3Id, @category4Id, @recipeById,
                            @totalTime, @totalTimeUnitId, @activeTime, @activeTimeUnitId, @instructions, @sourceKey, @recipeBy, getutcdate(), @isVerified, @numPersons, @servingsUnitId, @servingsUnitOrig)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have trouble because of your first record

```
SELECT ISNULL (MAX (ID), 0) + 1 FROM [dbo]. [Recipe]
```